# How to export SAS EG table to HTML file using SAS code

Tags: sas, export, enterprise-guide, ods

I'm trying to export SAS table to local HTML file using ODS HTML.
How can I do so?

```
data=WORK.TABLE_NAME;
ods html file="/user_data/maexport/monitoring t-1.html";
ods html close;
```

The code above saves html file, but it is empty.

Comment: ODS destinations basically redirect the output you would see in the Results window to a different format. So first make sure you code works as is, to get what you want and then wrap it in the ODS statements. Why HTML? It's not often you see an HTML table generated these days. I would highly recommend using HTML5 instead of HTML though, it's much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file is empty because you did not run any code that would have written something to the file between the command to open it and the command to close it.

```
ods html file="/user_data/maexport/monitoring t-1.html";
proc print data=WORK.TABLE_NAME;
run;
ods html close;
```